# Event listener not responding without any error in console

Tags: dom, event-listener

i tried to search for a solution for my problem but couldnt find anything that could lead to a solution.
The event listener is not responding anymore to a defined event.
There is no error in the console since similar problems occured when i missed to import a required variable or the related DOM Element couldnt be found by any reason.

I made my first steps with the debugger in Chrome and checked other events.
Going step by step through any other event the event listener shows me the code that defines the event.

Interesting is that when i click on the icon that usually triggered the event the debugger doesnt show the code for the event and shows instead the general event in the handler_manager.js (see below)

```
   `handleEvent(e: InputEvent | RenderFrameEvent, eventName?: string) {

       if (e.type === 'blur') {
           this.stop(true);
           return;
        }`
```

I checked that the elements are available since they were generated by mapbox.js and they can be selected via inspector by hovering over them.

```
 `let mapStations = document.querySelectorAll(".mapboxgl-marker");

  for (let i = 0; i < mapStations.length; i++) {
  mapStations[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("event")
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = valueArray[i];
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = labelArray[i];
  myChart.update("active");
 });
}`
```

i just  added the console.log for testing purpose but i dont receive the log.

Maybe one of you have an idea?

Kindest David

I tried to fiy an event listener that was working earlier.